VS Code ignoring target specific include path order from CMake targets
I am developing on a cross-compiling SW project with a structure looking roughly like below. Using Visual Studio Code with CMake and "CMake Tools" extensions. In this scenario, two executables are created which have their own set of source files (like main.c), however they have some shared code. And for this shared code, additional configuration is used, contained in the files called libconfig.h which are included from libapi.h.
And the way to ensure that the proper config header is loaded is by having a correct order or -I... parameters, i.e. explicit target_link_directories for each target in the CMake configuration, so that it's own include folder comes first.
But with VS Code I get a problem here. It seems like the include directory list per-target is basically not considered, and IntelliSense reads the first file of the same name found anywhere in the filesystem, and takes only those contents into evaluation. For example, when editing comp2/src/main.c the comp2/include/libconfig.h is ignored and comp1/include/libconfig.h is used instead (this is also opened when I try to navigate there). Which breaks the syntax highlighting heavily. I have tried selecting the explicit Build target in the CMake tab but that does not fix anything. I have purged the data folder with cache in the user profile folder and that was not effective either.
I know from other IDEs where one can select the target scope and this actually has an impact on the evaluation. Is the same possible with VSCode somehow?
Side note: another thing I have noticed is that it reports parsing errors on some non-standard keywords in certain headers due to an unusual compiler. Might that have an impact on the problem?
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── Toolchain.cmake
├── comp1
│   ├── include
│   │   └── libconfig.h
│   └── src
│       └── main.c
├── comp2
│   ├── include
│   │   └── libconfig.h
│   └── src
│       └── main.c
└── libX
    ├── include
    │   └── libapi.h
    └── src
        └── libsrc.c


The most reliable workaround I have found is using the CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS option. With this (but only when CppTools extension is installed), one can type IntelliSense in the Command Pallete, which offers the option to choose the data source. And then one can select the relevant compile_commands.json file. Once this is set, the navigation through Ctrl-Click seems to work correctly within the source which belong to the selected build target.
